# Publish code coverage not finding coverage file in Azure DevOps

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, jestjs, code-coverage

I'm using Node `14.x` and Jest `26.x`. There is a `npm test` script in package.json file which contains the following:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage --forceExit
```

When I run it locally, it generates the code coverage report in `./coverage` directory. The contents of `./coverage` directory is as follows:

```
lcov-report (folder)
clover.xml
coverage-final.json
lcov.info
```

It looks like `clover.xml` contains code coverage report. There are more details which can be found in `lcov-report` folder.
I've setup the Azure DevOps pipeline as follows for code coverage:

```
...
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml'

# Publish code coverage results
# Publish Cobertura or JaCoCo code coverage results from a build
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/clover.xml'
```

After running the pipeline, Azure DevOps doesn't seem to find the `cover.xml` file. I get the following error:

```
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Report directory: /home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml
Reading code coverage summary from '/home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage/clover.xml'
##[warning]No coverage data found. Check the build errors/warnings for more details.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[codecoverage.publish codecoveragetool=Cobertura;summaryfile=/home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage/clover.xml;reportdirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp/cchtml;]
```

I also tried the following options for `summaryFileLocation` but all resulted in same error.

```
'**/coverage/clover.xml'
'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage/clover.xml'
```

I understand that the format of `clover.xml` may not be the same as `Cobertura` or `JaCoCo`, but at least Azure should be able to locate the file.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way accidentally.

It looks like `Jest` can generate `cobertura` coverage report. It needs to be added in Jest configuration. I've added the following in `jest.config.js`:

```
coverageReporters: ['text', 'text-summary', 'clover', 'cobertura']
```

`Jest` generated the `cobertura` coverage file in:

```
./coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
```

Next I modified Azure pipeline file as follows:

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml'
```

After this changes, when I run the pipeline, Azure DevOps can find the file and show coverage report!